# Split in series PHP

Tags: php

i have this string `++++++1DESIGNRESULTSM25Fe415(Main)`

and i have similar string about 2000 lines from which i want to split these..

```
[++++++] [1] [DESIGNRESULTS] [M25] [Fe415] [(Main)]
```

from the pattern only the 2nd 4h and 5th value changes

eg.. `++++++2DESIGNRESULTSM30Fe418(Main)` etc..

what i actually want is:

1. Split the first value [++++++]
2. Split the value after 4 Character of [DESIGNRESULTS] so ill get this [M25]
3. Split the value before 4 Character of [(Main)] so ill get this [Fe415]
4. After all this done store the final chunk of piece in an array.

the similar output what i want is

```
Array ( [0] => 1  [1] => M25  [2] => Fe415 )
```

Please help me with this...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: `preg_split('([++++++]+[0-9])',$st,-1);` im new to coding... ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data split needs are a bit unclear.  A regular expression that will get separate matches on each of the chunks you first specify:

```
(\++)(\d)(DESIGNRESULTS)(M\d\d)(Fe\d\d\d)(\(Main\))
```

If you only need the two you are asking for at the end, you can use

```
(\d)DESIGNRESULTS(M\d\d)(Fe\d\d\d)
```

You could also replace `\d\d` with `\d+` if the number of digits is unknown.

However, based on your examples it looks like each string chunk is a consistent length.  It would be even faster to use

```
array(
   substr($string, 6, 1)
   //...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
 $str = "++++++1DESIGNRESULTSM25Fe415(Main)";

 $match = array();
 preg_match("/^\+{0,}(\d)DESIGNRESULTS(\w{3})(\w{5})/",$str,$match);
 array_shift($match);
 print_r($match);
```

Comment: also can you guide me how to do this in series like looping the entire string which match this pattern..

Comment: what does your full string looks like?

Comment: like this

1DESIGNRESULTSM25Fe415(Main)Fe415(Sec.)LENGTH:1500.0mmCROSSSECTION:300.0mmX600.0mmCOVER:40.0mm**GUIDINGLOADCASE:15ENDJOINT:13SHORTCOLUMNREQD.STEELAREA:5472.00Sq.mm.REQD.CONCRETEAREA:174528.00Sq.mm.MAINREINFORCEMENT:Provide12-25dia.(3.27%,5890.49Sq.mm.)(Equallydistributed)

<br/>

I need to get some values from the string in an order...thats what im trying to achieve...

Comment: But I can only see one instance of 1DESIGNRESULTSM25Fe415(Main). I am sorry but I am not clear on your question? do you want only that instance in your array or are there more in that string??