# split and regular expression in php

Tags: php

Right now i have this

```
***FIRST***1DESIGNRESULTSM25Fe415
***Second***Fe415
***Third***1500.0mm
***Fourth***300.0mmX600.0mmCOVER:40.0mm
***Fifth***15ENDJOINT:13SHORTCOLUMN
***Sixth***5472.00Sq.mm.REQD.CONCRETEAREA:174528.00Sq.mm
***Seventh***12-25dia.(3.27%,5890.49Sq.mm.)(Equallydistributed)
***Eighth***8mm
***Ninth***300mmc/c
***Tenth***Puz:3666.60Muz1:292.98Muy1:124.69
***Eleventh***

(NOTE This line need to be removed 0.96(asperCl.39.6,IS456:2000)+++++15ENDJOINT:13Puz:3792.15Muz:320.53Muy:133.87IR:0.85)

***FIRST***1DESIGNRESULTSM25Fe415
***Second***Fe415
***Third***1500.0mm
***Fourth***300.0mmX600.0mmCOVER:40.0mm
***Fifth***15ENDJOINT:13SHORTCOLUMN
***Sixth***5472.00Sq.mm.REQD.CONCRETEAREA:174528.00Sq.mm
***Seventh***12-25dia.(3.27%,5890.49Sq.mm.)(Equallydistributed)
***Eighth***8mm
***Ninth***300mmc/c
***Tenth***Puz:3666.60Muz1:292.98Muy1:124.69
***Eleventh***

(NOTE This line need to be removed :0.96(asperCl.39.6,IS456:2000)++++++15ENDJOINT:13Puz:3792.15Muz:320.53Muy:133.87IR:0.85)
```

First i need to split the values between ***First*** & ***Eleventh*** and get the final out put in this series...

```
[1]
[M25]
[Fe415]
[Fe415]
[1500.0mm]
[300.0mmX600.0mmCOVER:40.0mm]
[15ENDJOINT]
[5472.00Sq.mm]
[12-25dia.(3.27%,5890.49Sq.mm.)]
[8mm]
[300mmc/c]
[Puz:3666]
[Muz1:292]
[Muy1:124.69]
```

I tried some other method of doing this but unfortunately it dint work ;(

Also there are 2000 line of the same string.... my next step is to insert each record into a excel sheet.

Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: Post the code/methods you've attempted thus far so that we can better understand your goal.

Comment: the code is nothing but a simple explode function just im using it multiple times in different pattern. and being very honesty it a big mess already. but its doing the work till this far. now i need to chop rest of the pieces to finish up the first stage of my work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just build a tiny script, which is doing the job.

You have to put your logfile string into variable **$input**. It can be even hundreds of log blocks. Just try it yopurself,...

Here you go:

```
<?php

$input = 'YOUR_LOG_GOES_HERE';

$splitParts = preg_split('/.*?NOTE\sThis\sline.*?\n/', $input);

foreach ($splitParts as $key => $part) {
    $values = splitValues($part);

    /**... do somthing with values...  like put them in an excel sheet
     *  or just print them out
     */
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($values);
    echo '</pre>';
}


function splitValues($part)
{
    $splitted = preg_split('/\n/', $part);
    $data = array();

    /** Match 1. row **/
    $match = array();
    preg_match_all('/\*\*\*.*?\*\*\*(.*)?DESIGNRESULTS([a-zA-Z]{1,}[0-9]{2})(.*)/', $splitted[1], $match);
    $data[] = $match[1][0];
    $data[] = $match[2][0];
    $data[] = $match[3][0];

    /** Match 2. - 4. row **/
    for ($i=2; $i <= 4; $i++) {
            $data[] = matchRow($splitted[$i]);
    }

    /** Match 5. row **/
    $match = array();
    preg_match_all('/\*\*\*.*?\*\*\*(.*)?:.*$/', $splitted[5], $match);
    $data[] = $match[1][0];

    /** Match 6. row **/
    $match = array();
    preg_match_all('/\*\*\*.*?\*\*\*([0-9]{1,}.*)?\.REQD.*$/', $splitted[6], $match);
    $data[] = $match[1][0];

    /** Match 7. row **/
    $match = array();
    preg_match_all('/\*\*\*.*?\*\*\*(.*)?\(.*\)$/', $splitted[7], $match);
    $data[] = $match[1][0];

    /** Match 8. - 9. row **/
    for ($i=8; $i <= 9; $i++) {
            $data[] = matchRow($splitted[$i]);
    }

    /** Match 10. row **/
    $match = array();
    preg_match_all('/\*\*\*.*?\*\*\*(Puz:[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,})(Muz1:[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,})(Muy1:[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,})$/', $splitted[10], $match);
    $data[] = $match[1][0];
    $data[] = $match[2][0];
    $data[] = $match[3][0];

    return $data;
}

function matchRow($row)
{
    $match = array();
    preg_match_all('/\*\*\*.*?\*\*\*(.*)/', $row, $match);

    return $match[1][0];
}
```

Here's the code for the new string:

```
<?php
$input = '#1-M25Fe415-Fe415-1500.0mm-300.0mmX600.0mm-40.0mm-15-5472.00Sq.mm-174528.00Sq.mm-12-25dia.(3.27%,5890.49Sq.mm.)-8mm-300mmc/c-Puz:3666.60Muz1:292.98Muy1:124.69-';

$data = array();
$data = preg_split('/-/', $input);

$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/(Puz:[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,})(Muz1:[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,})(Muy1:[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,})$/', $data[13], $matches);

$data[13] = $matches[1][0];
$data[14] = $matches[2][0];
$data[15] = $matches[3][0];

print '<pre>';
print_r($data);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: and how you do the same with this string...#1-M25Fe415-Fe415-1500.0mm-300.0mmX600.0mm-40.0mm-15-5472.00Sq.mm-174528.00Sq.mm-12-25dia.(3.27%,5890.49Sq.mm.)-8mm-300mmc/c-Puz:3666.60Muz1:292.98Muy1:124.69-

Comment: Just one simple preg_split and another regex for the last values. It isn't that hard as it looks like. Go and try yourself. :) I edited my answer above and pasted the new code.

Answer (score 1):

Im not getting the pattern that you try to achieve here..

Are you trying to remove all

```
***Somestring***
```

However, I dont understand the pattern 
from the first value 1DESIGNRESULTSM25Fe415

to get

[1]

[M25]

[Fe415]

Comment: the above string is the final output from the log file. which i cant do anything...

then and when it comes to the splitting we can create a explode function with an array of delimiter. in my case ***First***, ***Second*** etc. but not sure how will i remove the rest of the unwanted piece strings.. also please refer to my previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528205/split-in-series-php